# How to use new table that create within a transaction

Tags: sql, delphi

When I create a table within a transaction this table is not accessible in transaction but all other table that created before transaction are accessible.
How can I solve this problem?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var MyAdo:TADOQuery;
    a,b:integer;
begin
  AdoConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=MyPCNAME'
  MyAdo:=TAdoQuery.Create(Application);
  MyAdo.Connection := ADOConnection1;
  MyAdo.SQL.Add('Create table tempdb..test1 (TBID int) '
              +' Insert Into tempdb..test1 Values (1) '
              +' Insert Into tempdb..test1 Values (2) '
               );
  MyAdo.ExecSQL;

  ADOConnection1.BeginTrans;

  MyAdo.SQL.Clear;
  MyAdo.SQL.Add('Create table tempdb..test2 (TBID int) ');
  MyAdo.ExecSQL;


  MyAdo.SQL.Clear;
  MyAdo.SQL.Add('Select max(TBID) Mx1 From TempDb..Test1 ');
  MyAdo.Open;
  A:=MyAdo.FieldByName('Mx1').AsInteger;        //Result:2

  MyAdo.SQL.Clear;
  MyAdo.SQL.Add('Select max(TBID) Mx2 From TempDb..Test2 ');
  MyAdo.Open;
  B:=MyAdo.FieldByName('Mx2').AsInteger;        //Deadlock!!!!!!!!! It need to force the application to close

  ADOConnection1.CommitTrans;
end;
```

Comment: Try by creating a stored procedure in your dbms and put all sql code on that. Afterwards, invoke the stored procedure in your delfi code.

Comment: On a side note, why are you using the `master` database? You're supposed to create your own...

Comment: @Jerry Dodge: Above code is sample. In the original code I read/write to different databases, So I first connect to master and read/write to other databases with (DatabaseName..TableName). I haven't problem for read/write to these databases but when I create temp table in tempdb I can't read from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code as follows

```
  [...]
  MyAdo.Close;
  MyAdo.SQL.Clear;
  MyAdo.SQL.Add('Select max(TBID) Mx2 From TempDb..Test2 with (nolock)');
  MyAdo.Open;
  B:=MyAdo.FieldByName('Mx2').AsInteger;   //  No Deadlock
```

This works for me without blocking on SS2014.  But I think you might do better to read around the subject, starting with f.i.
[SQL Server SELECT statements causing blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017177/sql-server-select-statements-causing-blocking)

Btw, contrary to what is said in that q, setting the AdoConnection's IsolationLevel to ilReadUncommitted did not avoid the blocking with your original code.