# Can Select block a table from Insert?

Tags: sql-server

If I am performing SELECTS on a table, is it possible that a SELECT query on a table can block INSERTS into the same table?

A SELECT will take a shared lock on the rows, but it shouldn't effect inserts correct?

**The query is a LIKE clause - will this block an insert?**  Does it have the potential?

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Description LIKE '%HELLO%'
```

Reference:
I read this response [SQL Server SELECT statements causing blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017177/sql-server-select-statements-causing-blocking/1017203#1017203) and I am confused how this would block an insert.

Comment: Is that `SELECT` statement taking up all the resources on your server?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I updated my Q with the query - what resources are you referring too?

Answer (score 4):

> A SELECT will take a shared lock on the rows, but it shouldn't effect
>   inserts correct?

No, it's not exact.
When you make a `SELECT`, it can acquire `shared locks` on `pages` and even on the whole `table`,
you can test it by yourself by using `paglock` or `tablock` hints (of course you should use `repeatable read` or `serializable` to see them, as all the `shared locks` in `read committed` are released as soon as they are no needed anymore).

The same situation can be modelled this way:

```
if object_id('dbo.t') is not null drop table dbo.t;

select top 10000 cast(row_number() over(order by getdate()) as varchar(10)) as col
into dbo.t
from sys.columns c1 
     cross join sys.columns c2;

set transaction isolation level serializable;

begin tran
    select *
    from dbo.t 
    where col like '%0%';

    select resource_type,
           request_mode,
           count(*) as cnt
    from sys.dm_tran_locks
    where request_session_id = @@spid
    group by resource_type,
             request_mode;
```

[image]

Here you see `lock escalation result`, my query wanted more than 5000 `locks` per `statement` so instead of them server took only one `lock`, `shared lock` on the `table`.

Now if you try to insert any row in this table from another session, your `INSERT` will be blocked.

This is because any insert first need to acquire `IX` on a `table` and `IX` on a `page`, but `IX` on a table is incompatible with `S` on the same table, so it will be blocked.

This way your `select` could block your `insert`.

To see what exactly happens on your server you should use `sys.dm_tran_locks` filtered by both your `session_id`.

Comment: ok so that 5K lock is because the table has millions of rows..so a WHERE LIKE '%hello%' will perform a table scan since the column isn't indexed either...do you agree?

Comment: No. First of all your condition WHERE Description LIKE '%HELLO%' has '%' as the begin of string so no index can be used (at least for seek). Second, if you are operating under READ COMMITTED, lock escalation will not trigger as any lock is released as soon as the row is read. It was only an example. To find the cause in your case you should look into sys.dm_tran_locks to find out conflicting locks

Answer (score 1):

General info - this is called `SQL Server Concurrency` and in `SQL Server` you will find two models:

- Pessimistic;
- Optimistic.

Answering your question - yes, you can block any insert during read and this is called "Pessimistic Concurrency". However, this model comes with specific properties and you have to be careful because:

- Data being read is locked, so that no other user can modify the data;
- Data being modified is locked, so that no other user can read or modify the data;
- The number of locks acquired is high because every data access operation (read/write) acquires a lock;
- Writers block readers and other writers. Readers block writers.

The point is that you should use **Pessimistic Concurrency** **only** if the locks are held for a short period of time and **only** if the cost of each lock is lower than rolling back the transaction in case of a conflict, as Neeraj said.

I would recommend to read more about isolation levels applying both **Pessimistic** and **Optimistic** models [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017).

**EDIT** - I found a very detailed explanation about isolation levels on Stack, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034976/difference-between-read-commit-and-repeatable-read).

Comment: So can you explain how the SELECT will block the insert?  The insert is not effecting the rows in the SELECT because it is a brand new row.

Comment: The query I am using is in my question, I'm not doing repeatable reads...

Comment: Sorry, I confused `REPEATABLE READ` with `SERIALIZABLE`. So, `SERIALIZABLE` means that locks are acquired on the range of values being read and are held until the end of the transaction, transactions cannot read uncommitted data, and cannot modify the data being read by other transactions until the transaction completes; another transaction cannot insert or delete the rows in the range of rows being read. How is the `INSERT` being made? Through a stored procedure?